# xmpp Chat application shows 401 un authorised

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

When i created one to one chat it works perfectly when i try to join in a group chat this error displayed what could be the reason need help

i used the same connection for the single chat and also that connection for joining the group chat .

my code is this

```html
public void groupChatter() {


        Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

        try {
            mMultiUserChat = new MultiUserChat(connection, room + "@conference.nubes-pc-1");
         //   mMultiUserChat.create(room);
            mMultiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
            mMultiUserChat.join("test user 1");
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.groupchat);

            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet)
                {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null)
                    {
                        String from = message.getFrom();
                        String Body = message.getBody();
                        // Add incoming message to the list view or similar
                        Log.d("Errro", from+" "+Body);
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }
        });
        t1.start();
    }
```

```html
02-16 17:11:07.028  24028-24245/nubes.logic.chatapp D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq id='gYQVr-4' to='room1@conference.nubes-pc-1' type='set'><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner"><x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'></x></query></iq>
02-16 17:11:07.118  24028-24246/nubes.logic.chatapp D/SMACK﹕ RCV (0): <iq type="error" id="gYQVr-4" from="room1@conference.nubes-pc-1" to="test1@nubes-pc-1/Smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"/></query><error code="401" type="auth"><not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
02-16 17:11:07.148  24028-24290/nubes.logic.chatapp W/System.err﹕ not-authorized
02-16 17:11:07.168  24028-24290/nubes.logic.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:196)
02-16 17:11:07.168  24028-24290/nubes.logic.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:175)
02-16 17:11:07.168  24028-24290/nubes.logic.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(MultiUserChat.java:590)
02-16 17:11:07.168  24028-24290/nubes.logic.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at nubes.logic.chatapp.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:205)
02-16 17:11:07.178  24028-24290/nubes.logic.chatapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your room persistent or create it everytime you want to chat. 
 OR just use

```
mMultiUserChat.createOrJoin(room);
```